# Symfony Undefined namespace

Tags: php, symfony

I am seeing namespace errors all over the place and I am not sure why.

For exampe I have:
`use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;`
and `Configuration` is in red and the error reads:

```
Undefined namespace Configuration less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Referenced namespace is not found.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Confirm you have files in your vendor folder, if not run composer install to add them

Comment: I noticed that it did not install my vendor folder locally. I am using a remote server for my local environment. I am going to download the vendor folder to my local machine and see if that helps.

Comment: That was my issue. I was missing the vendor folder.

Answer (score 5):

Since you say "`Configuration` is in red" I assume the problem you are experiencing is related to the IDE

If you are using PHPStorm there's a specific Symfony plugin that handle all the namespacing pretty much automatically, as long as your setup is standard.
By standard I mean a project dir containing the app/ src/ web/ ... dirs (if you're using the 2.x Symfony dir layout)

[This link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+Started+-+Symfony+Development+using+PhpStorm) will tell you everything you need, in great detail

Answer (score 0):

It may be your .idea folder which is corrupted. Close your project, delete the .idea folder and restart the IDE. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).